# Loop in a loop python

Tags: python

is there a way to add a second loop to a code. So the question says to create a quiz which I've done however, for the last hour I've being trying to add a second loop so the quiz does it three times:

```
import random
score = 0
questions = 0
loop = 0
classnumber = ("1", "2", "3")
name = input("Enter Your Username: ")
print("Hello, " + name + ". Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz")

classno = input("What class are you in?")
while classno not in classnumber:
    print(
        "Enter a valid class. The classes you could be in are 1, 2 or 3.")
    classno = input("What class are you in?")
while questions < 10:
    for i in range(10):
        number1 = random.randint(1, 10)
        number2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        op = random.choice("*-+")
        multiply = number1*number2
        subtract = number1-number2
        addition = number1+number2

        if op == "-":
            print("Please enter your answer.")
            questions += 1
            print(" Question", questions, "/10")
            uinput = input(str(number1)+" - "+str(number2)+"=")
            if uinput == str(subtract):
                score += 1
                print("Correct, your score is: ", score,)
            else:
                print("Incorrect, the answer is: " + str(subtract))
                score += 0

        if op == "+":
            print("Please enter your answer.")
            questions += 1
            print(" Question", questions, "/10")
            uinput = input(str(number1)+" + "+str(number2)+"=")
            if uinput == str(addition):
                score += 1
                print("  Correct, your score is: ", score,)
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " + str(addition))
                score += 0

        if op == "*":
            print("Please enter your answer.")
            questions += 1
            print(" Question", questions, "/10")
            uinput = input(str(number1)+" * "+str(number2)+"=")
            if uinput == str(multiply):
                score += 1
                print("  Correct, your score is: ", score,)
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " + str(multiply))
                score += 0
```

Comment: Basically you can just add a `for game_num in range(3):` before the part of your code you want to repeat and indent the lines below it one level. Alternatively you can make the repeated part a function and call it three times.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to repeat? You already have two loops in the main body of the code, a `while` loop and a `for` loop, though since they're counting the same things effectively (`questions` is always identical to `i`), you don't get any benefit.

Comment: I meant the questions so the for I in range thing

Comment: But why do you want an extra loop? Why not just change your existing `for` loop to go to 30, if you want 3 times 10 questions?

Comment: Because the code needs three scores from each person who takes the quiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please consider using functions in your code. Functions make everything neater and functions help make code reusable.

Second, there are a lot of areas where the code is superfluous. It is performing unnecessary checks in spots and several sections of the code could be rearranged to reduce the overall length and increase readability.

Nonetheless, here's a revised version of your code with some of those suggestions implemented:

```
import random

def RunQuiz():
    name = input("Enter Your Username: ")
    print("Hello, " + name + ". Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz")

    score = 0
    questions = 0
    loop = 0
    classnumber = ("1", "2", "3")
    classno = input("What class are you in?")
    while classno not in classnumber:
        print("Enter a valid class. The classes you could be in are 1, 2 or 3.")
        classno = input("What class are you in?\n>>> ")
    # End while input

    # Run the 10 question quiz
    for questions in range(1,11):
        number1 = random.randint(1, 10)
        number2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        op = random.choice("*-+")
        multiply = number1*number2
        subtract = number1-number2
        addition = number1+number2

        print("Please enter your answer.")
        print(" Question" + str(questions) "/10")
        if( op == "-"):
            # Subtraction
            uinput = input(str(number1)+" - "+str(number2)+"=")
            # Make it an int for proper comparison
            uinput = int(uinput)
            if uinput == subtract:
                score += 1
                print("Correct, your score is: %d" %(score,))
            else:
                print("Incorrect, the answer is: " + str(subtract))
                score += 0
        elif( op == "+"):
            # Addition
            uinput = input(str(number1)+" + "+str(number2)+"=")
            uinput = int(uinput)
            if uinput == addition:
                score += 1
                print("  Correct, your score is: %d" % (score,))
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " + str(addition))
                score += 0
        elif( op == "*" ):
            # Multiplication
            uinput = input(str(number1)+" * "+str(number2)+"=")
            uinput = int(uinput)
            if uinput == multiply:
                score += 1
                print("  Correct, your score is: %d" % (score,))
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " + str(multiply))
                score += 0
        # End if( op )
    # End For 10 questions
    print("\nFinal Score: %d/10" % (score,))
# End RunQuiz()

def main():
    # Run the quiz 10 times
    for RunCount in range(3):
        print("Running quiz #%d\n" % (RunCount,))
        RunQuiz()
    # End For
# End main

# Call main on script execution
main()
```

Obviously you can rearrange the code to suit your needs. (For example, I did not know if you want the name & class number to be entered every time).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole thing to run 3 times then put  `for i in xrange(3):` above the first lines of the quiz then indent the rest of the code to the loop. If that is what you actually want. Good luck!